# asp.net assigning roles to a user/Session from mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

What I have is a two tables.  One table with users and another table with user roles.  I know how to get the data out of the mysql DB, but how do I add all of those roles to my user?

I would normally thinking `Session.Add` but the problem is i have anywhere from 2-10 roles so any help would be grateful!

The purpose of this is I want to create a navigation bar that will display X amount of links based on whatever row they have, and also, to block certain features.

I've game up with this

```
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(storedProcedureName2, cn);
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@usernameID", userID);
                MySqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    string roleName = dr2["role"].ToString();
                    mysql
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(userID, roleName);
                }
```

However this will not comes back with timeout contact sql server.  How do I convert that to use MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at implementing your own `Membership` and `Roles` Providers:

- [Implementing a Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx)
- [Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)

Comment: Why not just use the Role Provider that comes with MySQL?

Comment: The benefit is he would be able to use his existing tables and data without having to transform them into the structure required by those Providers.